# Geth 1.5.9 on Windows Server 2012 r2 stops

Tags: go-ethereum, windows

I'm runing Mist 0.8.9 on Windows Server 2012 R2 and I'm having problems with node syncronisation. I run command in powershell:

> .\geth.exe --datadir D:Ethereum

and I got this:

```
I0419 15:08:37.764496 node/config.go:445] Failed to start Ledger hub, disabling: libusb: not found [code -5]
I0419 15:08:37.765663 ethdb/database.go:83] Allotted 128MB cache and 1024 file handles to D:\Ethereum\geth\chaindata
I0419 15:08:37.805467 ethdb/database.go:176] closed db:D:\Ethereum\geth\chaindata
I0419 15:08:37.806468 node/node.go:176] instance: Geth/v1.5.9-stable/windows/go1.7.4
I0419 15:08:37.806468 ethdb/database.go:83] Allotted 128MB cache and 1024 file handles to D:\Ethereum\geth\chaindata
I0419 15:08:37.863469 eth/backend.go:187] Protocol Versions: [63 62], Network Id: 1
I0419 15:08:37.864469 eth/backend.go:215] Chain config: {ChainID: 1 Homestead: 1150000 DAO: 1920000 DAOSupport: true EIP
150: 2463000 EIP155: 2675000 EIP158: 2675000}
I0419 15:08:37.865469 core/blockchain.go:219] Last header: #0 [d4e56740] TD=17179869184
I0419 15:08:37.865469 core/blockchain.go:220] Last block: #0 [d4e56740] TD=17179869184
I0419 15:08:37.865469 core/blockchain.go:221] Fast block: #0 [d4e56740] TD=17179869184
I0419 15:08:37.868508 p2p/server.go:340] Starting Server
I0419 15:08:40.002570 p2p/discover/udp.go:227] Listening, enode://9ef9ff367d0d1fc0e4d6718a3712fed9656e8d9b1b3016738a7b48
877620c2655c8a93725ee75aa22097bf4caa55df309b31644906cf2437485faf640fe3a5b8@[::]:30303
I0419 15:08:40.006567 p2p/server.go:608] Listening on [::]:30303
I0419 15:08:40.006567 node/node.go:341] IPC endpoint opened: \\.\pipe\geth.ipc
```

Here is stucked and it's not starting sync at all. Does anyone know what should I look or do in this situation?

Thank you in advance,
Tomislav

Comment: Hi there. A few ideas. Try running `geth.exe attach` from another terminal (i.e. another instance of `cmd`) and check the number of peers you're connected to by running `admin.peers`. If you have no peers, ensure TCP and UDP ports 30303 are being forwarded by any firewalls that might be between you and the outside world.

Comment: Hello! There are no peers, so I went to check port forwarding. I have runned `netstat -an` and I see folowing:
`Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State` - 

`TCP    [::]:30303             [::]:0                 LISTENING` -

`UDP    [::]:30303             *:*`
Does that mean that ports are forwarded properly?

Comment: Also I tried to `telnet IP 30303` from other compuer and it's working. Besides that, server is on VPN of company where I work. This computer that telneted server is also on same VPN. Is it possible that VPN might be the cause of problem? If yes, what should I check then?